# Sharepoint Books

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint. I want to learn sharepoint, but the problem is i am not from a developer's background. So can you suggest some books which help me to learn sharepoint right from the scratch.

Comment: Start by looking at [other stackoverflow questions](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fquestions+sharepoint+book) that have covered this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by 'Not from Developer background'?
Here's what you can consider

1. First time SharePoint developer/user
   No prior programming experience but has knowledge of Web or Portal development (includes HTML and Javascript)
   Visit http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/
   The stuff here is not free but the investment is worth the knowledge you gain.
2. New to programming
   No prior programming experience whatsoever, no idea about Web or Portal development either.
   This is going to take TIME more than anything and considering you want to learn SharePoint, think twice about the investment. I don't mean to dissapoint you but if you are willing to put in atleast 8 to 10 hours a day for the next 3 months (the 3 is a variable!!!) then start with what a Website is and get to know about the fundamentals of Web development. This is not rocket science but it aint trivial either, so get ready, it will be exciting.
   Visit http://tutsplus.com/
   They have some free stuff on HTML and Web development.
   The bottom line is you should be ready to invest TIME in both the scenarios because SharePoint is a different beast to tame and at time it would seem like it's too much of work to do. Be patient and let the fundamentals seep in and you will see the results.
   And yes, give books third priority, consider getting a subscription for either Tuts+ or PluralSight.
   PS:
   I don't work for either of the sites but believe me you will see the difference between a book and a video based learning.

All the best.